# Access Jenkins pipeline definition within Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

For a project I would like to know which branch is used to check out the pipeline script that is used. In this case I would get back that the branch is */develop

[Job Definition example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaJIC.png)

Solved by using this:

```
String url = 'curl --user  '  + "${JENKINS_USER}:${JENKINS_PASS}" + ' https://jenkinsurl/job/'+ env.JOB_NAME + '/config.xml'
    
String CICD_BRANCH = new XmlSlurper().parseText(url.execute().text).definition.scm.branches."hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec".getProperty("name").toString().substring(2);
        
env.CICDBRANCH = CICD_BRANCH.toString()
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about your question? Base on you job definition, I think all of the branches match the Regex `*/develop` will be used for the build process.

Comment: Hm, maybe I have to make it more clear.

Within a Jenkins job you can define where the Jenkins pipeline is coming from (inline of via scm). In case it is configured that the pipeline can retrieved from a Git repo, you can also set the branch which should be used to retrieve the pipeline.

And in that pipelinescript I want to retrieve what branch is configured in the Job config.

Comment: I have fixed this myself by using the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current `branch name` in your `pipline` script you can use the below code.

```
echo "My branch is: ${scm.branches[0]}"
node('build_node') {

}
```